# Call method in existing Com Application from my .NET application

Tags: .net, com-interop

There is a scenario I'm interested in. 
User runs COM based application in a separate window, I want my C# application to manipulate that application through COM calls. I've found COM interface I'm interested in and VisualStudio has successfully generated wrapper (MyApp.interop). So I can write something like `new Interop.MyApplication()` but I do not want new Application I want to work with existing one.

Comment: How would you do that from non .NET application?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to _automate_ the UI of the com application through .NET?

Comment: For example, It is Ms. Word and I want it to open document. Though, It's another application really (MapInfo 6.5)

Comment: I am not sure COM allows to 'connect' to running application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution, code looks like

```
var app = Marshal.GetActiveObject("MapInfo.Application")
((MyApp)app).OpenFile(...)
```